# Adding dynamically CalendarExtender to a WebForm in CodeBehind

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, ajaxcontroltoolkit, code-behind, calendarextender

I'm trying to add dynamically a control `CalendarExtender` from **ASP.NET Ajax Toolkit** to the WebForm page. When I'm accessing the WebPage, where I've coded this control to be added - I've got an error:

**MissingManifestResourceException**

*Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "AjaxControlToolkit.Properties.Resources.NET4.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "AjaxControlToolkit" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.*

Piece of code, where does occur the error:

```
// set User birthdate
Label labelUserBirthdate = new Label();
labelUserBirthdate.ID = "editableLabelSecondName";
labelUserBirthdate.Text = "Bithday: ";

TextBox editableBirthdate = new TextBox();
editableBirthdate.ID = "editableTextBoxBirthday";
editableBirthdate.CssClass = "round default-width-input";

CalendarExtender birthdateCalendar = new CalendarExtender();
birthdateCalendar.ID = "calendarExtender" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
birthdateCalendar.TargetControlID = "editableTextBoxBirthday";

this.contentViewWebdata.Controls.Add(labelUserBirthdate);
this.contentViewWebdata.Controls.Add(Page.ParseControl("<br />"));
this.contentViewWebdata.Controls.Add(editableBirthdate);
this.contentViewWebdata.Controls.Add(birthdateCalendar);
this.contentViewWebdata.Controls.Add(Page.ParseControl("<br />"));
```

Full code (problem does occur on `SetSceneEditableUserInfo()` ):

- ASPX Markup: http://ideone.com/8deRFr
- CodeBehind: http://ideone.com/yOOyGK

I have searched in Web such topics and other people do the same things:

- just include namespace with AjaxControlToolkit
- Make new instance of the CalendarExtender
- set ID
- set Target ID

As you see I'm doing the similar stuff. Why does it argue on Resources? I don't understand:

- the correct DLL is included
- the namespace was included in CodeBehind too.

How can I fix my issue?

Comment: Did you specified "auto" or "ru-RU" setting for `uiCulture` attribute of `globalization` element of web.config?

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy no, I haven't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solved by myself.

The problem occured because I forgot to add dynamically the `ToolkitScriptManager` control to the page. Now it's working.